# How to convert the json image url string into Bitmap image to display images in android application

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, database

I am developing an android application,in that i want to fetch images from server database.i used json to fetch images from server database to android application (images folders are in file system).But when i use that getImages.php link in my android app ,i can't see images .it says that String(url of images)can't be converted into Bitmap.Suggest me the next step.
Any help is appreciated.
Thank You

Comment: where is the code? what have u tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Volley`'s `ImageRequest`, to update your ImageView via JSON image `URL`.

```
ImageRequest imageRequest = new ImageRequest(image_url_coming_from_json, new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(final Bitmap response) {

                        your_imageView.setImageBitmap(response);
            }
        }, 0, 0, ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE, null, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(your_activity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(your_activity.this);
        requestQueue.add(imageRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NetworkImageView instead of ImageView.